# git add Autocomplete with Zsh and oh-my-zsh and Ambiguity

Tags: git, autocomplete, addition, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm a new user of zsh and oh-my-zsh. The git completions are really nice, but one that really drives me nuts is the "git add" autocomplete. Currently what happens if I type "git add " is it does what I expect: it tries to autocomplete but only with the modified files in the working tree. However, if I type enough to disambiguate which file I'm looking for, I would expect the completion to simply finish the rest of the file name, but it doesn't; it pauses at each directory, requiring an additional  to complete the full filename.

I've recorded an asciiio screencast to demonstrate the problem here: http://ascii.io/a/4457

Answer (score -1):

While less than ideal, the results are the same. If `directory1/somedir/somefile.txt` is the only file in `directory1/somedir` that has changed, then `ga directory1/somedir` and typing `ga directory1/somedir/somefile.txt` will have the exact same effect.

Basically, you can safely ignore any weirdness.

Comment: I'm not really worried about safety per se. I just want the autocomplete to "do the right thing". In my case, "the right thing" means once I've disambiguated what I want to add, it should fully complete (path and all). I do realize however that this is not standard path completion behavior, and may be difficult to implement.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably an upstream issue.